# “gyp ERR! stack” with NodeJS, but XCode Command Line Tools in installed

Tags: node.js

After I install new npm package i get this error:

```
No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/local/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
```

But if i tried to install the XCode Command Line Tools `xcode-select --install` I got the next message: xcode-select: error: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` My ios version is `Big Sur`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**First option**
Disclaimer usually this is not enough from Big Sur macOS onwards, so you have to do second (longer) approach described bellow.

```
# reset your XCode Command Line Tools
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

**Second option**
Reinstall XCode Command Line Tools:

```
# gets the path
xcode-select --print-path

# use returned path
sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

# install it again
xcode-select --install
```